# How to ONLY list the Group Roles with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, list, roles

I'm trying to list the group roles in PostgreSQL.
Not Users,
Not Users + Group Roles,
Only Group Roles.

As I know,

This is how to list only Users :

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_shadow;
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_user;
```

& here's how to list Users + Group Roles :

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_authid;
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_roles;
```

SO NOW,
I just want to list ONLY Group Roles.

Hope you can help me...

Comment: There is `SELECT * FROM pg_group;` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @memosdp, the following answer is correct :

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_group;
```

Comment: FWIW, in my system, this returned some of our newer individuals as well, with just 0 or 1 items in the `grolist`. Perhaps that's because pg doesn't really distinguish and someone starting using the group syntax to set up individuals - IDK.